# Flutter Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI in Flutter_map

Tags: flutter, dictionary, url, mapbox, fluttermap

I'm creating a map in an Android application using **flutter_map package** and using **MapBox**, I was actually trying to get a vector tile but always ended up making a raster tile anyway so I gave up on it today, it displayed fine and the URL was valid, till I tried to move that code to anther file for organizing purposes (it worked once though) and I don't know where it went wrong but suddenly it shows a blank page with an error that says:

> Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URL

While it's the same URL but when I pasted it into Chrome it didn't work as the pic below even that I checked the style I'm using in MapBox million times so the URL should be all right!

[Web error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1RWU.png)

I also tried a ready-map style that it succeed before, Am I typing the URL wrong or what? I'm a beginner in maps and Flutter itself.

Here's the code of FlutterMap widget:

```
FlutterMap(
        options: MapOptions( 
          center: LatLng.LatLng(24.266906,45.107849),
          zoom: 4.8,
          adaptiveBoundaries: false,
        ),
        children: [ 
          TileLayer( //style_id: clmly80au01ts01qucmxh0meq
                     //access_token: pk.eyJ1IjoiaWhlYm0iLCJhIjoiY2xtbHhuOHY2MGowcTJzczd5NTFzOTFpNyJ9.1CIj8NONC6vfgGiNrJoHIw
            urlTemplate: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/ihebm/clmly80au01ts01qucmxh0meq/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiaWhlYm0iLCJhIjoiY2xtbHhuOHY2MGowcTJzczd5NTFzOTFpNyJ9.1CIj8NONC6vfgGiNrJoHIw',
            tileSize: 512,
          ),
        ],
),
```

I typed what I tried above.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posting the solution on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space)*.

After many tries, this worked for me... I'm actually not sure about the reason because it must be almost as same as what I did also try, but it works :D

```
  FlutterMap(
    options: MapOptions( 
      center: LatLng.LatLng(24.266906,45.107849),
      zoom: 4.8,
      adaptiveBoundaries: false,
    ),
    children: [ 
      TileLayer(
      urlTemplate: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/ihebm/clmly80au01ts01qucmxh0meq/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiaWhlYm0iLCJhIjoiY2xtbHhuOHY2MGowcTJzczd5NTFzOTFpNyJ9.1CIj8NONC6vfgGiNrJoHIw',
      additionalOptions: {
           'accessToken': 'pk.eyJ1IjoiaWhlYm0iLCJhIjoiY2xtbHhuOHY2MGowcTJzczd5NTFzOTFpNyJ9.1CIj8NONC6vfgGiNrJoHIw',
           'id': 'clmly80au01ts01qucmxh0meq'
        }
        ),
    ],),
```